# Task.Continuewith equivalent in RX

Tags: system.reactive

I have a scenario to start a subscription once another subscription is completed. Both are sharing the same connected stream.

```
IConnectableObservable<List<int>> stream = GetMyHotStream();
var firstSubscription = stream.Subscribe(s=>{});
var secondSubscription = stream.Subscribe(s=> {});
stream.Connect();
```

Now I would like to wait the `secondSubscription` until the `firstSubscription` is finished.

I omitted other details for brevity.

Any answer will be very helpful.. Thanks

Comment: "Now I would like to wait the secondSubscription until the firstSubscription is finished." - this sentence doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do from a higher-level perspective

Comment: What I am looking is var secondSubscription = stream.WaitUntil(firstSubscriptionCompleted).Subscribe(s=> {});

Comment: It would be interesting to see your actual use case. There may be (probably is) a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're trying guarentee the order in which the two subscriptions execute. The problem is that as set up, they are independent. I think that the best solution is just to put them in one operation.

```
stream.Subscribe(s =>
{
   FirstSubscriptionStuff(s);
   SecondSubscriptionStuff(s):
});
```

Comment: Correct. I am trying to guarentee the order of the exeuction. I cannot combine the logic in single subscribe as the results in the firstsubscription (Which is list of values) are updated on the UI first and the enriching of the result happens for each of the result in the second subscription which takes long time as it connects to another service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where the first subscription prints out "Sub 1 item" each time there is an update to a hot observable. I use Take(5) to ensure the first subscription completes.
The 2nd subscription will then continue to take items from the original source afterwards.

```
var s = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Publish();

var sub1 = s.Take(5).Dump("Sub 1 item");
var sub2 = sub1.IgnoreElements().Concat(s).Dump("Sub 2 item");

s.Connect();
```

Output:

```
Sub 1 item →0
Sub 1 item →1
Sub 1 item →2
Sub 1 item →3
Sub 1 item →4
Sub 2 item →5
Sub 2 item →6
Sub 2 item →7
```

Is this the sort of thing you are after?
Regards,

Howard

Answer (score -1):

I wrote something like

```
public static IObservable<TSource> WaitUntil<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, IObservable<Unit> completionSource)
    {
        return new WaitUntil<TSource>(source, completionSource);
    }
```

and implemented WaitUntil by Subscribing to the source in OnCompletion of completionSource.

The usage of this is

`var asyncSubject = new AsyncSubject();`

```
        var secondStream = stream.WaitUntil(asyncSubject).Subscribe(s =>
            {
            });

        var firstStream = stream.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread).Subscribe(s =>
            { },
            () => 
            {
                asyncSubject.OnCompleted(); 
             });

        stream.Connect();
```

Not sure how elegant this is as i just started on using Rx in my projects, but this works fine.